# Use Kotlin in Library

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk, kotlin

I have some android sdks already written in java.

I am wondering if it is unsafe to rewrite them in Kotlin. I imagine that if the `$kotlin_version` is different between my code and my customer one, it mays not compile. Am I right ? (same for kotlin android-studio plugin)

Comment: refer this Link >> [click here](https://medium.com/@tomoima525/rewriting-android-library-with-kotlin-339f30ed548b)

Comment: Yeah, that kind of article is why I am asking. When I read:
`Error:Conflict with dependency 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib' in project ':app'. Resolved versions for app (1.1.2-4) and test app (1.1.2-3) differ. See http://g.co/androidstudio/app-test-app-conflict for details.` I keep wondering if I am right not to write my sdks in kotlin. However, kotlin-version is 1.2.41 now : 41 possibilities not to compile properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since kotlin for Android is more mature and since Gradle provides tools that helps us implementing dependencies in shorter scope, this question is not relevant anymore.